# Creating and using DLL in Symbian c++

Tags: symbian

i am new in symbain. i have no idea how to create symbian dll and using it in a symbian application.

**i am looking some sort of tutorial or guide for:**
 1. how to create a dll in symbian c++?
 2. how to use the created dll in an symbian app?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start at [hemelix](http://www.hemelix.com/Programming-details), especially [here](http://www.hemelix.com/symbian-dll) and [here](http://www.hemelix.com/Polymorphic%20DLL), then take a look at the official documentation at [Nokia Symbian Belle Developers' Library](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Nokia_Belle_Developers_Library/GUID-86C9DACB-DCCF-43F6-BCEE-91144F4EADC8_cover.html) which also contains examples (for example [here](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Nokia_Belle_Developers_Library/GUID-176FD8C9-B4A9-5B50-B683-AB5DA7D5D6F4.html) and [here](http://library.developer.nokia.com/topic/Nokia_Belle_Developers_Library/GUID-960B2F4E-9012-53EE-973A-C3426A7DD48F.html)).

(Let me warn you though: Symbian development is really tough. Think twice before diving in...)

Comment: thank you very much. the links are really helpful. i will go through all the links in details and will let you know.